# How to serve Video response without downloading the whole video on browser

Tags: python, pyramid, zodb

I am using Pyramid with ZODB as Database storage. I want to return video response and I am able to but the only problem is browser downloads the whole video and then plays it and I don't want that to happen. I wanted to stream video but I am unable to find any proper solution.
Here's my code

Function which returns video response is:

```
@view_config(context=Content, name='getcontentplay')
def getContentImage(context,request):
    blob = context.blobdata
    resp = Response(content_disposition="inline; filename=\""+blob.filename.encode('utf-8')+"\"",content_type=blob.contentType,)
    resp.app_iter = blob.data
    resp.content_length = blob.size
    return resp
```

And Blob Storage Class is:

```
from ZODB.blob import Blob
from persistent import Persistent

class BlobWrapper(Persistent):
    def __init__(self, filedata,contentType,filename):
        self.contentType = contentType
        self._blob = Blob(filedata)
        self.filename = filename

    def _getData(self):
        fp = self._blob.open('r')
        data = fp.read()
        fp.close()
        return data

    def retFile(self):
        return self._blob.open('r')

    data = property(_getData)

    @property
    def size(self):
        if 'size' in self.__dict__:
            return self.__dict__['size']
        reader = self._blob.open()
        reader.seek(0,2)
        size = int(reader.tell())
        reader.seek(0)
        reader.close()
        self.__dict__['size'] = size
        return size

    def getSize(self):
        return self.size
```

And My HTML Template Code is

```html
<video   poster="/static/images/kid.png" controls controlsList="nodownload" preload="none">
    <source src="${urltovideo}" />
</video>
```

Comment: I have had trouble with encodings that record the "this is how to load this video" information at the end of the file instead of the beginning. Are these all custom videos in a single format?  If that might be the case try downloading a generic working video from another site and trying it.  I'm posting only a comment because I'm hazy on the details and I think more info is needed.   The blob thing could be a problem but it also might have nothing to do with the actual problem, hope that makes sense. So ... How are the videos encoded?  Have you tried videos from other sources?

Comment: Also, just to let you know, I use pyramid to pass off movie requests to Nginix with a 'X-Accel-Redirect' header, mainly in an mp4 format.  I embed a jwplayer (proprietary but works for me) that handles cross browser displaying of the videos.

Comment: @plantian I am having trouble understanding you the code works just fine the only problem is that the browser loads the whole video first and then plays it. Suppose If I upload a video of 20MB I would have to wait for browser to load 20MB before I can see the video playing. And also I have just edited the question for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: At the very least, I think you need to be setting HTTP Accept-Ranges header on response, something like resp.accept_ranges = 'bytes'.  This is likely necessary, but I am unclear if sufficient.

Comment: thank you @sdupton for the suggestion I have tried that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to get a chunked/streaming response and the details of this are entirely dependent on your wsgi server and any other servers/proxies between the wsgi server and the client's browser. For example nginx will, by default, buffer the entire response from its upstream before sending the response to the client. Also many WSGI servers will do the same to a certain degree and you need to look at their settings for how to tune that buffering.

Comment: do you have any links which i can refer to?